# Typescript inheritance error

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Hi I have the following error in typescript:

```
class A {
    constructor() {};
    protected func1() {
        this.func2();
    }
    protected func2() {
        alert('hello');
    }
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
         super();
         super.func1();
    }
}
```

I found this error: TypeError: this.func2 is not a function

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This compiles for me. Are you sure this is exactly the code you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

The code above won't cause `this.func2 is not a function` error. However, it incorrectly implements inheritance. `super.func1` is supposed to be used only if `func1` was shadowed in child class, otherwise it's inherited from parent and can be accessed on class instance:

```
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
         super();
         this.func1();
    }
}
```